# How to release and renew IP address from DHCP on Linux systems?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Systems:

- Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit (desktop mode, hands-on)
- GNU/Linux Debian 9.2 Cinnamon 64-bit (headless mode, SSH)

Question:

How to release and renew IP address from the DHCP server (router) on these Linux systems?

Comment: If all you want to do is refresh your lease, you can use `dhclient -v eth0` - replace `eth0` with whatever your device is actually named

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found there is the following program listening on the network on both of them:

```
dhclient
```

Quoting the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient):

> ```
> -r     Release the current lease and stop the running DHCP client as  previously  recorded
>        in  the  PID  file.  When shutdown via this method dhclient-script will be executed
>        with the specific reason for calling the script set.  The client  normally  doesn't
>        release  the  current  lease  as this is not required by the DHCP protocol but some
>        cable ISPs require their clients to notify the server if they wish  to  release  an
>        assigned IP address.
> ```

---

So, the solution for all interfaces would be:

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient
```

Or, conveniently, for a specific interface, say `eth0`:

```
sudo dhclient -r eth0
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Of course, when SSH'ing into a server, you need to run both commands *oneliner* or write a script as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251464/126755).

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, because usually dhclient gets called automatically by some other part of your system, e.g. `systemd`. So if you start meddling manually, the part calling dhclient may get confused.

Comment: @dirkt Ok, feel free to add a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

on ubuntu:

release:

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

renew:

```
sudo dhclient -1
```

Comment: Why is ```dhclient -1``` better than just plain ```dhclient```?  Please  do  not respond in  comments; [edit]  your answer to  make it clearer and  more complete.